# How to sort my dictionary by all elements from a list in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, tuples

```
dict = {'Name': '1', 'Content': ' a b c d e f g', 'Name': '2', 'Content': ' a h i j k l m', 'Name': '3', 'Content': ' a h n o p q r', 'Name': '4', 'Content': ' s t u v w x y'};
```

(maybe my dict should be a tuple, I dont know what's best :))

```
list = (a, h, n)
```

(the list elements will not always be the same, they will be selected by the user with a input, and the added to the list)

Now i want to print all my dictionaries key-value-couple that contains at least one of the list elements. And before printing it I want to sort the output by decreasing order how many times the list elements appears in the value of the dictionary.

The output should sorted like this:

```
Name: 3, Content: a h n o p q r 
Name: 2, Content: a h i j k l m
Name: 1, Content: a b c d e f g
```

I don't want it to print `"Name: 4, Content: s t u v w x y"` because a,h or n is not in the value.

Sorry for my bad python-language, will be very grateful for the help! :)

Comment: ok, any attempts from your side?

Comment: Let's start with the fact that you cannot have the same key in a dict multiple times...

Comment: I think you want a list of dicts instead. As @deceze points out, you cannot have duplicate keys in a dict. `[ {'Name': '1', 'Content': ' a b c d e f g'}, {'Name': '2', 'Content': ' a h i j k l m'}, ... ]`

Answer (score 1):

You no need dict here, because dict can't store few same keys. If you use list or tuple, you also no need to sort result, just build your list in appropriate order and check it successively:

```
elements = ((4, 'stuvwxy'), (3, 'ahnopqr'), (2, 'ahijklm'), (1, 'abcdefg'))
search = ('a', 'h', 'n')

for name, content  in elements:
    if any(x in content for x in search):
        print "Name: {}, Content: {}".format(name, content)
```

UPD

If you need sort elements:

```
elements.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```

Comment: `any` can take a `genexpr` so you don't need to make a `list-comprehension`, i.e. `any(x in content for x in search)` should work just as well (and be helpful with long search lists, which doesn't seem to be the case here).

Comment: the letters: a,b,c,d.... represent different words, does it make any difference? Do i just write: elements = ((1, 'I' 'will' 'have' 'some' 'words' 'here').....) or elements = ((1, 'I will have some words here')....) ?

Comment: but what if the user wants different input, then it wont be sorted right... How do I sort please help! :) the whole point is that I want to sort it depending on what input the user write!

Comment: You can sort elements using sort method.

Comment: but how do I sort this? I want to sort by the frequency of search in elements

Comment: Try to do it by yourself. If you can't create another question.